# Trying to load external resources on Firebase function

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to upload a YAML file **during** the deployment and use it.

How can I do this on Firebase functions? I added the file, but when I try to read it the file  does not exist

```
await fs.readFile(path.resolve('./manifest.yaml'), 'utf-8')
```

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/workspace/manifest.yaml'

**My question is**: Is it possible to deploy additional files on Firebase Functions?

[image]

Comment: Your screenshot should show more clearly where exactly manifest.yaml lives within your project.  I'm also not clear what you mean by "during development".  Who or what is invoking that code?  Please edit the question to be more clear, providing instructions on how someone would reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths to deployed files in Cloud Functions are not relative to the source code file where you want to load them.  They always going to be relative to the root folder of the deployment.  That means the manifest file is more likely located at "./lib/src/triggers/manifest.yaml" if "functions" is your project deployment root.